# Uncaught ReferenceError: stripeResponseHandler is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into a credit card form.

The js and html can be viewed at http://pastie.org/private/f4flb1hktzdahl9snr4jma (for reference, jquery is included in the head of the document)

For some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stripeResponseHandler is not defined
```

The error is triggered on line 11:

```
Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Based on this, it appears that the Stripe.js is not being loaded correctly? However, the line `Stripe.setPublishableKey('something');` works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the variable `stripeResponseHandler`?

Comment: The code is gone at pastie.org (as of 3Nov2022).  This is why you should include a minimum example in your original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

You are missing parts of the code, see here: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Comment: I just did the same thing.

Comment: broken link, as of 3Nov2022, but I accepted the rest of the answer.